# Not able to connect cosmo table api using datafactory

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Keys are stored in secret as "**cosmostablekey**" for cosmos table api.

Created another secret stored in key valuets as below.

```
{
"name": "CosmosDbSQLAPILinkedService",
"properties": {
    "type": "CosmosDb",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "AccountEndpoint=https://XXXXXXX.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/;Database=TablesDB",
        "accountKey": { 
            "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret", 
            "store": { 
                "referenceName": "ls_cosmos_key"", 
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference" 
            }, 
            "secretName": "cosmostablekey" 
        }
    },
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    }
}
```

}

when try to create linked service used authentication type as key authentication in adf  and tried for test connection got below error.

Error code
9082
Details
**The CosmosDb key is in a wrong format.
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
Activity ID: f0c9c682-12de-4b53-95e9-7abe7ea722b7.**

am sure copied key strig properly to key vaults.

Used for refence to connect cosmos db from adf.

[microsoftdoctoconnectcosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=data-factory)

Thanks for quick help.

Comment: That documentation points to SQL API. Try this instead for table storage, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage?tabs=data-factory

Comment: My requirement is metadata wil be placing in cosmos table api. Need to connect it from datafactory and process it further

Answer (score 1):

Issue is got resolved

Need to call only **cosmostablekey** key in linked services for key athentication. More over need to specify endpoint as

https://XXXX.documents.azure.com:443/
instead of https://XXXX.table.azure.com:443/

Working fine for me now..